# For what values of $a \in \mathbb{R}$ , is there no solution to $e^x-a=\ln(x+a)$

Tags: calculus, analysis

I considered each expression as being a function like

$f:(-a, \infty )\rightarrow \mathbb{R}  $

$f(x)=e^x-a$

AND

$g:(-a, \infty )\rightarrow \mathbb{R}  $

$g(x)=\ln(x+a)$

By " not having solutions "I understand that the graphs have to have no common points of intersection. I tried this way to actually draw the graphs with no proper result because of the a varies.

I tried making a unique function like

$h:(-a, \infty )\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$h(x)=e^x-a-\ln(x+a)$

and apply the Rolle's Theorem, but didn't succeed.

How do I approach it? Sorry for the bad English, I tried my best.

Comment: At least $x=-a$.

Comment: Why restrict the domain of $f$?

Comment: because if the g has a domain, the f can't have a different domain because there is an ecuation between those two

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\ln(x+a)$ is in fact the inverse function of $e^x - a$. A function and its inverse are reflections around the $y=x$ axis, so we only have a solution if $e^x - a$ intersects $y=x$ So  we only need to check if there are solutions to $e^x = a+x$. We can do this by noting the tangent to $e^x$ at $0$ is $x+1$ and the entire function lies above this line; we therefore only have solutions when $a \ge 1$, and no solutions when $a<1$.

Comment: Thank you for answering!